# How to find number of way that a postage of n cents can be made by 4, 6, 10 cents?

Tags: math, recurrence

For example,

n = 4 (4x1) 1 way

n = 10 (4x1, 6x1) (10x1) 2 ways

Is there any equation can express the number of way?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about [math.se] instead of programming or software development.

Answer (score 0):

You have used `recurrence-relation` tag - yes, it is possible to use recurrence to calculate the number of ways.

```
P(N) = P(N-10) + P(N-6) + P(N-4)
P(0) = 1
```

Explanation - you can get sum N, using (N-10) cents sum and 10-cent coin and so on.
For rather large values of N recursive algorithm will work too long, so one could build dynamic programming algorithm to accelerate calculations (DP will reuse calculated values for smaller sums)

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have a list of denominations. In your case it is A = [4,6,10]. So suppose you have the following things:

```
A = [4,6,10]
Length of list A = N
Sum = K
```

The problem can be written as:

```
# Given the list of denominations, its length and the sum.   
P(A,N,K) =  0 if N < 0 or K < 0,
            1 if K = 0,
            P(A,N-1,K) + P(A,N-1,k-A[N])  #A[N]-> Nth element of list
```

As we can see the possibility of re-using sub-problems, DP will work wonderfully.